# How to convert JavaScript Date to Java date-time with a time-zone?

Tags: javascript, java

Is there a simple way to convert a [JavaScript Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) to a Java 8 date-time with a time-zone?

I have a web application which consists of two parts, front end is written in JavaScript and the back end in Java. A user should be able to select a date-time in UI and the value should be consumed by the back end. What is the easiest way of converting this value to Java date-time?

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd provide more description in your question. Presumably you asked this knowing you were about to answer it, which is fine - but if anyone else were trying to answer, they'd need more detail... so you should provide that detail *as if* you didn't know the answer to start with. That way it will be more helpful for future readers.

Comment: up voted because "it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged."  See: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “JavaScript Date”? The [spec for ECMAScript 2017](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-date-objects) says the string format for a date-time is a simplification of the ISO 8601 standard: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert time using The Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) and ZonedDateTime, for example:

```
Thu, 31 Mar 2016 06:49:02 GMT
Thu, 31 Mar 2016 06:49:02 -0830
```

**JavaScript**

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toUTCString();
```

[toUTCString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toutcstring.asp) method converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time. For example, `console.log(n);` will print out a result:

```
Tue, 17 Mar 2020 08:59:19 GMT
```

**Java 8**

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME);
```

text is a UTC date and time string
[ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) is a date-time with a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system
[RFC_1123_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) is a predefined RFC-1123 date-time formatter.

Printing `zdt` for the above example value will produce:

```
2020-03-17T08:59:19Z
```

Comment: seems that your are answering your self in less than 1 min

Comment: Please wait for others to reply , they may come up with better way. Once answered , people tend to avoid answering.

Comment: @Panther: There's nothing wrong with self-answering. If the OP faced a problem and then solved it, then asking a question and answering it immediately is fine IMO. https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions. Admittedly the question itself could be written more clearly.

Comment: @Panther Indeed, as Jon Skeet noted, answering your own Question is not only *allowed* on Stack Overflow, it is *encouraged*. See the two links in the second comment by Roberto on the Question.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed.I too answer sometime however, it is better to wait for sometime.

Comment: @BasilBourque I too encourage answer own question , as if it is not resolved by others . OP has more chances to resolve it as he has to fix it somehow. Just wanted him to wait day or two for other to have look.

Comment: @Panther No, why should OP wait? When asking a question, there is the option to self-answer immediately, this possibility is intended. It doesn't prevent other users from posting answers as well.

Comment: Your javascript code looks interesting, but I wish you had posted the output string. I need to know how it will be formatted.

Comment: @MiguelMunoz, I have updated the answer with an example output string.

Comment: Not a bad answer, but it requires manual parsing of the date String in Java. You cannot let it parse automatically.

Comment: @Akito please share examples of 'parsing automatically'.

Comment: @Boris https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial You want to parse the model automatically. Though, with your method, you need to provide a custom option to `ZonedDateTime.parse()`. It does not work automatically, as shown in the cases within the link above.

Comment: @Akito the linked document doesn't contain any examples of parsing JavaScript Date to Java date-time.

Comment: @Boris Indeed. The concept and idea is the same, though. It's about not doing any manual parsing, but letting it parse automatically.

Comment: @Akito, I believe it's impossible, but since you disagree, please provide a concrete example of parsing it "automatically".

Answer (score 0):

use [ZoneId.of(String zoneID)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-)

```
ZoneId.of("UTC");  
ZoneId.of("-08:00");
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do this in a web application with a Java server backend and Javascript running the browser. The problem was that the Javascript code that built the Request to be sent to the server was closed to my code, so I was unable to call any specific methods on the instance of the Javascript Date object to control the formatting. Thus the `toString()` method was being implicitly called and the resulting string looked like:

`Mon Sep 28 1998 14:36:22 GMT-0700 (PDT)`

when using Chrome, Firefox or Safari

Digging into the [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) reveals that this method calls `toDateString(tv)` where `tv` is the time value of the Date instance.

Unfortunately it seems to be up to the implementing flavour to decide how exactly this ends up being displayed:

> Return an implementation-dependent String value that represents tv as a date and time in the current time zone using a convenient, human-readable form.

So we can't be sure that all browsers will format the date the same way when `.toString()` is called but anecdotally I observed the same format when I tested with a few browsers and changed the region settings, language and calendar to a variety of interesting ones (such as Ethiopian) and I still ended up with the same date format.

Working on the assumption that it's consistent, we can now parse the date in Java using the following:

`ZonedDateTime zdt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z (z)")`

which preserves the Time Zone information sent by the client.

Anyway, I hope this is useful to someone else, and I'd be grateful if anyone can point to any documentation as to the (in)consistency of Javascript Date `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use momentjs, here's something simple that can be consumed easily by Java8:

```
var zone =  moment.tz.guess();
var localDateTime = moment("2018-11-17T11:43:13").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');    
console.log(localDateTime + '[' + zone + ']');
```

produces (in my timezone):

```
2018-11-17T11:43:13-05:00[America/Toronto]
```

And on the Java8 side:

```
final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-11-17T11:43:13-05:00[America/Toronto]");
```

Comment: This but without additional dependencies would be great.