# Error installing fluentd-ui while building own Docker image

Tags: docker, fluentd

I am trying to build a customized Docker image based on Fluentd's [v1.2-debian](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-docker-image/blob/master/v1.2/debian/Dockerfile) image with [fluentd-ui](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-ui) browser-based manager. I added some additional packages as per the [requirements](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-ui#requirements):

```
RUN buildDeps="sudo make gcc g++ libc-dev ruby-dev build-essential libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev" \
```

But the build fails with this error:

```
Error installing fluentd-ui:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.4/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20180903-647-puzk49.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.3.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
...
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message points to a missing zlib dependency. You can fix it by adding a compression library [zlib1g-dev](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/zlib1g-dev) to the build dependencies list:

```
RUN buildDeps="sudo make gcc g++ libc-dev ruby-dev build-essential libssl-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev" \
```

Now you should be able to build a Docker image with fluentd-ui installed.

Comment: Immediatly [self-answering question seems ok](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253050/2648551), because requirement was not mentioned on https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-ui and this can help others.

Comment: @colidyre Thanks for re-iterating Jon Skeet's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36327539/how-to-convert-javascript-date-to-java-date-time-with-a-time-zone/36327550#comment60277763_36327550) on self-answering.